# What is the use of ACL behavior?

Tags: cakephp, acl

I don't know the use of ACL behavior in cakePHP? I've read the documentation and still don't understand when can we use it and why.

Thank you.

Comment: This may helps: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/coeus/2008/03/12/acl-behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this two link may help you. these are explained with example.

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Tutorials-Examples/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application.html

and

http://junalontherun.com/2010/11/27/a-simple-cakephp-access-control-list-acl-tutorial/